# Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am creating sample app for payment using https://pub.dev/packages/eghlflutter.
In this they have made few changes from eghl-sdk-v2.5.2.aar to eghl-sdk-v2.5.7.aar but when using this lib through pubspec.yaml. Its downloading old eghl-sdk-v2.5.2.aar not
eghl-sdk-v2.5.7.aar because of that payment page not working.
When I downloaded full project from github and run it, its working fine but not working as dependency

Tried :
Flutter clean and flutter upgrade

Error :

Execution failed for task ':eghlflutter:bundleDebugAar'.

> Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :eghlflutter project caused this error: /Users/mac/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/eghlflutter-1.1.1/android/eghl-sdk/eghl-sdk-v2.5.2.aar

Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:eghlflutter/eghlflutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _eghlPaymentResult = 'Awaiting for payment.';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('eGHL Payment'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center (
            child: Column (
              mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(this._eghlPaymentResult),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("Pay"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _Pay(context);
                  },
                  color: Colors.amberAccent,
                  textColor: Colors.black,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  splashColor: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  void _Pay(BuildContext context) async {
    String result = '';
    String paymentId = 'SIT${new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}';

    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> payment = {
        'TransactionType': 'SALE',
        'Amount': '1.00',
        'CurrencyCode': 'MYR',
        'PaymentId': paymentId,
        'OrderNumber': paymentId,
        'PaymentDesc': 'Testing Payment',
        'PymtMethod': 'ANY',

        'CustName': 'somebody',
        'CustEmail': 'somebody@someone.com',
        'CustPhone': '0123456789',

        'MerchantReturnURL': 'SDK',
        'MerchantCallBackURL': 'SDK',

        'ServiceId': 'SIT',
        'Password': 'sit12345',
        'LanguageCode': 'EN',
        'PageTimeout': '600',
        'PaymentGateway': true,
        'EnableCardPage': false,
        'TriggerReturnURL' : true,
      };

      result = await Eghlflutter.executePayment(payment);
    } catch(e) {
      result = 'error';
    }

    setState(() {
      _eghlPaymentResult = result;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Yes.Removed dependency and pub get. Again added like this
 eghlflutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/eGHL/flutter-plugin-eghl.git

      ref: master.